# Launch activity from library class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-library

I've created a small library which acts as a base to provide functionality for my classes. Inside the library I occasionally find myself needing to launch a new Activity but Android always gives me a Null Pointer Exception, are libraries not allowed to start new activities or am I just doing something wrong?

Here's some of the library file that sends the Intent:

```
videoIntent = new Intent(Interface.this, com.package.name.Video.class);
videoIntent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
startActivity(videoIntent);
```

I get the Null Pointer Exception on the last line.

I've tried replacing `Interface.this` with `getApplicationContext()` but that just changed the location of the NPE to that line.

My package name is decleared in both the Manifest of the library project and the project utilizing it.

LogCat:

```
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2858)
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2964)
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at com.spherical.adspire.Interface$3.onTouch(Interface.java:98)
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3761)
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:871)
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:871)
09-22 17:19:16.485: E/AndroidRuntime(7378):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:871)
```

In case it makes a difference `Interface` extends the `Activity` class and my project class extends `Interface`.

Comment: added the activity to launch in manifest ?

Comment: Both activities are declared in the Manifest.

Comment: Remember to declare the activities in the Manifest of the Application that uses this library. The manifest of the library is useless.